# Following TF tutorial running into error initialising container: parsing reference caused by '\'

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm on this step of the TF [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#2) -- funnily enough this is also my first time using Docker -- and although I successfully pulled the container in the previous step, I'm running into problems running the next few commands.

Some of the errors are below: [image]

Comment: I'm guessing that whoever wrote that command was expecting it to be run in Bash, where backslash characters indicate line continuations. Try removing the backslashes and concatenating the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I solved this by using '^' the equivalent symbol for CMD :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using '^' to mark multiple line CMD command.